# How to extract id3 tag from locally uploaded mp3 by fileReference? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, id3

In AS3(for flash) we can use FileReference class to browse a local mp3 file and pass the data to a ByteArray.
However, how can we extract the id3 tag in this way?

(there is a external library http://www.emanuelz.com.mx/blog/parsing-local-mp3-with-filereference-and-audiofx-library-106 that parse the bytearray into sound object, however, the id3 tags are missing. When you call sound.id3.songName it returns NULL.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load that `ByteArray`, then create a new `Sound` object, create a `ID3` event listener on that, and call `loadCompressedDataFromByteArray()`, this will make Flash parse the loaded file as MP3, and if it has ID3 tags, the event will be dispatched allowing you to read id3 data.

```
var themp3:Sound=new Sound();
themp3.addEventListener(Event.ID3,getid3);
themp3.loadCompressedDataFromByteArray(thefile,thefile.length);
// thefile is the ByteArray in question
function getid3(e:Event):void {
    if (e.target is Sound) {
        var s:Sound=e.target as Sound;
        trace(s.id3.songName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good question. There is another more advanced/manual method (bytes reading) that I'll add as answer later (incase future readers need it). Why? Just that Flash's ID3 parser doesn't handle certain things well for example Japanese `.songName` will be □□□□ instead of チェリ